# How to get value from page using WebDriver >> find elements

Tags: webdriver

How to get value from  hierarchy with Selenium WebDriver and WebElement?
The web page application is Telerik model.

Part of my **java code**:

```java
public void ChangeElementSaveAndVerify() throws InterruptedException
    {                       
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(myPrinterTab.printerTabIconLeftPane)).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);     
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(myPrinterTab.showHideDriverDetailed)).click();

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_RadGrid_Driver_ctl00_ctl05_EditFormControl_Preton_ucSettings_Driver_treeList_ctl04_Enabled_DropDown"));

            WebElement innerElemt = select.findElement(By.tagName("div"));
            WebElement innerElemt2 = innerElemt.findElement(By.tagName("ul"));
            List<WebElement> allOptions = innerElemt2.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

            for (WebElement option : allOptions) {

                System.out.println("Value is: "+ option.getText());
                System.out.println(option.getAttribute("value"));
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(myPrinterTab.arrowUsePreton)).click();
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                option.click();
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(myPrinterTab.saveButton)).click();

            }
```

**Page Source**

```html
<div class="rcbSlide" style="z-index: 6000; visibility: visible; display: block; overflow: visible; margin-left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 328px; left: 1122.5px; height: 42px; width: 370px;">
    <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_RadGrid_Driver_ctl00_ctl05_EditFormControl_Preton_ucSettings_Driver_treeList_ctl08_GraphicMode_DropDown" class="RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_Default " style="display: block; visibility: visible; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 368px;">
        <div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth" style="width: 100%; overflow: auto; height: 40px;">
            <ul class="rcbList" style="list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;zoom:1;">
                <li class="rcbItem "> … </li>
                <li class="rcbHovered "> … </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: GetText (); function is giving me NULL value and also the getAttribute("value")

Comment: And this is part of my page source -   <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_RadGrid_Driver_ctl00_ctl05_EditFormControl_Preton_ucSettings_Driver_treeList_ctl08_GraphicMode_DropDown" class="RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_Default " style="display: block; visibility: visible; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 368px;"><div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth" style="width: 100%; overflow: auto; height: 40px;"><ul class="rcbList" style="list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;zoom:1;"><li class="rcbItem ">Fast</li><li class="rcbHovered ">Brightness</li></ul></div></div>

Comment: `.getAttribute("value")` would never work but I'd expect `getText` to work, and I noticed you are using `innerElemt2` to find it's "inner" `li` elements. This is incorrect, considering the "outer" `ul` is under an element called `inner2Elemt`.....therefore I'd suspect it is picking up elements you are not expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The WebElement you are getting by `findElement` has no such attributes like a text value.
Try finding the correct WebElement by using a different By-Mechanism **(By.id or By.xpath)**.

If this is not working, post HTML so it is easier to help.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, 
My web application contains lots of combo box , free text box and buttons, therefore i'm looking for dynamic mechanism that will capture elements from page, the function should change value save it and verify it, the longest way is to save xpath for each value in page, but it is very complicate to do it

Comment: As far as i can see there is no WebElement in the page source which has a text attribute. Maybe there is a problem with the page source?

Comment: To echo Marco, from the HTML you have provided there are no 'value' attributes or text associated with the `li` elements. What exactly of these elements are you trying to capture and verify?

Comment: These elements are combo boxes values that generated by Telerik, i will send you again the page source of part from page that describes one of the combo box contains two values: 'Fast' & ' Brightness'

Comment: I am trying to get the value between the <li>...</li> tags. e.g. if there is <li>monitor</li> then I want to get the word monitor. Thanks in advance

Comment: Btw, I have tried using getText() but it seems to return an empty string every time. I also tried casting the WebElement to a RemoteWebElement but getText() still returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
options=driver.find_element_by_class_name("the class name in which u r text monitor is present")
for option in options:
temp=option.text
print temp
```

this is in python script and i think this idea will help u